# scrollspy doesn't work like in docs bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a scrollspy like in the bootstrap documentation. But I don't know why it doesn't work for me, I would like that when I go down the page depending on where I go down the scrollspy puts the color in the navbar, for example if I'm in the contact tab so that in the navbar there is the hover in contact or if I click on contact it goes down in contact. How should I do?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1aca141b14.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom" style="padding: 1%;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Avatar Logo" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Compétences</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">À Propos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -40%"
        data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example bg-light p-3 rounded-2" tabindex="0">

        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="images/114-1144561_copyright-free-images-on-desk-with-laptop-and.jpg"
                        class="d-block w-100" style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
                    <div
                        class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
                        <h1 style="font-size: 90px;">Développeur Web Indépendant</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/269-2698560_high-resolution-laptop-desktop-wallpaper-hd.jpg" class="d-block w-100"
                        style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
                    <div
                        class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <h1>Création de sites web</h1>
                        <h1>Site vitrine, e-commerce, forum et autres</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/10705380.jpg" class="d-block w-100" style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
                    <div
                        class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <h1>Web design, conception graphiques</h1>
                        <h1>Logos, plaquettes publicitaire, cartes de visites,
                            newsletters</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade"
                data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <section class="caseservices" style="padding: 4%;">
            <div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading1">
                <h1>MES SERVICES</h1>
                <h3 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Des prestations adaptées à vos besoins</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Gestion de projets web</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Site vitrine, corporate, évènementiel, e-commerce, intranet,
                                    application
                                    mobile.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Intégration Web</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Des intégrations (X)HTML / CSS respectueuses des standards du Web.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Développements spécifiques</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Des outils adaptés à votre coeur de métier,
                                    applications & solutions personnalisées.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Référencement naturel</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Affichage sémantique des informations,
                                    des pages propres pour un référencement optimal.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img class="img-fluid w-100"
                                        src="images/5902216.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img
                                        src="images/kisspng-icon-design-web-development-responsive-web-design-black-brush-5afd4d493dd9d2.7237427015265498332534.png"
                                        alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Conception graphique & Webdesign</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires,
                                    cartes de visite, newsletters...</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/3938579.png" alt=""
                                        style="width: 100%;"></i>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Dynamisme des pages</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Des animations de contenu non intrusives
                                    pour embellir votre projet.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/2739572-200.png" alt=""
                                        style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Interface d'administration</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Outils spécifiques au bon fonctionnement
                                    de votre entreprise.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/1027666.png" alt=""
                                        style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Responsive design</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application mobile.</p>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
        background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
        ),
        url(1393785.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                <div class="header-content">
                    <h4 class="text-center" style="color: white;">Compatible Mobile, Tablettes & P.C</h4>
                    <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;">Développement Web Responsive</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 4%;" href="scrollspyHeading3">
            <h1>MES COMPÉTENCES</h1>
            <h3 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Des compétences à votre service</h3>
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-start">
                        <h4>Domaines de compétences</h4>
                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i> Gestion de projets web
                        </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Site vitrine, corporate, évènementiel, e-commerce, intranet,
                            application
                            mobile.</p>

                        <h6> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Conception graphique &
                            Webdesign </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires, cartes de visite,
                            newsletters...</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Applications spécifiques
                            et
                            Interface d'administration</h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">PHP - MySQL - AJAX / ASP.NET - C# - SQL</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Mise en place /
                            Modification
                            / Gestion de CMS</h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Wordpress, Joomla, Prestashop, phpBB, IPBoard</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Intégration (X)HTML / CSS
                        </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Codage à la main respectueux des standards du Web</p>

                        <h6> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Dynamise des pages par
                            JavaScript / AJAX </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, Scriptaculous</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Validation W3C, WAI &
                            référencement naturel SEO</h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;"> Accessibilité & ergonomie des pages web </p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i> Conception
                            multi-plateformes
                        </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application mobile</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Compétences en développement</h1>
                        <div class="skills-bar">
                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>HTML/CSS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line html"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line javascript"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>PHP</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line php"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>laravel</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line python"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>MYSQL</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line mysql"><span></span></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 4%;" href="scrollspyHeading4">
            <h1>MES PROJETS</h1>
            <h4 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Une partie des projets sur lesquels j'ai travaillé</h4>

        </div>


        <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
        background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
        ),
        url(521120.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                <div class="header-content">

                    <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;"> PME, associations ou particuliers,
                        je réponds à vos besoins en développement web </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br>
        <h1 class="text-center" style="background-color: grey;">Une idée ? Un projet ? N'hésitez pas à demander un devis
            !
            [GRATUIT]</h1>


        <div class="container text-center" style="padding: 4%;" href="scrollspyHeading6">
            <h1>À PROPOS</h1>
            <h4 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Je suis développeur web freelance et j'aime ça !</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h4 class="text-start">Un développeur web passionné !</h4>
                    <p class="text-start">Ma passion pour le développement web commence en 2003 et m'a demandé un
                        changement
                        radical de cursus
                        afin de pouvoir pleinement l'exploiter.</br> </br>

                        Dès lors, je mis tout en oeuvre pour percer dans cette voie, tout en prenant du plaisir sur les
                        divers projets développés.</br> </br>

                        En Mai 2009, je décide de devenir développeur web indépendant après plusieurs postes en tant que
                        développeur web « full-stack » réussis, qui me conforteront dans cette idée afin de toucher un
                        plus
                        large panel de domaines d'activités, voir du pays et conquérir le monde !</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    <h4 class="text-start">Expérience en développement</h4>

                    <p class="text-start"> Mon expérience acquise au fil des projets me permet de mieux comprendre les
                        attentes d'un client
                        et de
                        répondre précisement au besoin demandé en fonction du domaine d'activité.</p>

                    <p class="text-start">Du site vitrine au projet plus complexe, je vous propose une expertise et un
                        développement web qui
                        correspond à vos attentes & à vos besoins.</p>

                    <h3 class="text-start">Un tarif adapté à votre projet</h3>

                    <p class="text-start"> Travaillant régulièrement avec des PME, associations ou particuliers, je vous
                        propose des solutions
                        à
                        votre portée & adaptée à votre budget.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
            background: linear-gradient(
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
            ),
            url(1393769.jpg);
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                <div class="header-content">
                    <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;"> Un interlocuteur unique pour un site internet réussi
                        !
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading7">
            <h1 style="padding: 4%;"><b>CONTACTEZ-MOI</b></h1>
            <h3 style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);padding: 1%;"><b>Une idée ? Un projet ? N'hésitez pas à
                    demander un devis !
                    [GRATUIT]</b></h3>

            <div class="row align-items-center" style="padding: 3%;">
                <div class="col text-start">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-geo-alt-fill w-100"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10"
                                    style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3px;  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                                    <h6><b>ADRESSE</b></h6>
                                    <p>45, allée des Grives 83390 Cuers</p>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-whatsapp"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10"
                                    style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 3px;  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                                    <h6><b>Téléphone</b></h6>
                                    <p>(+33) 6.15.42.10.45</p>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                    <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-10"
                                    style="padding-top: 3%; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);">
                                    <h6><b>E-mail</b></h6>
                                    <p>contact@mcrevoulin.com</p>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <iframe
                        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d84484.16954505828!2d7.69203969606045!3d48.56905316140801!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4796c8495e18b2c1%3A0x971a483118e7241f!2sStra%C3%9Fburg%2C%20Frankreich!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1658941325979!5m2!1sde!2sde"
                        width="300" height="400" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
                        referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
                    <!-- <iframe
                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d316530.06898113067!2d38.75890546037433!3d51.69843674434513!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x413b2f5ce874e813%3A0x48d94c0efba762bd!2sWoronesch%2C%20Oblast%20Woronesch%2C%20Russland!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1658941426253!5m2!1sde!2sde"
                    width="300" height="200" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"
                    referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <form id="contactForm">

                        <!-- Name input -->

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom Prénom" aria-label="Nom Prénom"
                                aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        </div>


                        <!-- Email address input -->
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-label="mail"
                                aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>  
                     
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>

@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
* {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}


/* Modify the background color */

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37);
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.nav-link .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  font-size: 39px;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: cyan;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2.5px 0 0 cyan;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  color: cyan;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2.5px 0 0 cyan;
}


/**/

.caseservices {
  background-image: url('114-1144561_copyright-free-images-on-desk-with-laptop-and.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item>img {
  -webkit-animation: thing 20s;
  -o-animation: thing 20s;
  animation: thing 20s;
}

@keyframes thing {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want click contact or any other navigation link it will go to specific section right?

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this

change href to id in your contact section (same for other links )

`<div class="container text-center" href="scrollspyHeading7">`

to

`<div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading7">`

Comment: Thank you very much, it's solved so that it redirects to the href, so that it shows the color in navbar when you're in the section, how do you do it?

Comment: Then accept my answer and upvote! :) you can edit your question and click ctl+m this pop the html css js code you can paste in it. this will runs your site perfectly

Comment: Ok i do to this post is resolved